# Error en unión de dos datatable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatables, datatable

Tengo un error al unir dos `datatable` ya que me genera un error que dice:

> Las columnas primarias y las columnas secundarias no tienen columnas que coincidan.

y las dos columnas existen en las dos tablas

```
SqlConnection conSQL = new SqlConnection();
conSQL.ConnectionString = "x";
conSQL.Open();

consulta = "select A.TICKET,A.STATUS_DE_SOLICITUD,D.RAZON_SOCIAL,D.ID_OPERADOR,d.CLAVE_EMPRESA,A.CODIGO_TAG,D.NUMERO_ECONOMICO,SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(25),A.FECHA_HORA, 120),1,10) as FECHA_CRUCE,SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(25),A.FECHA_HORA_CRUCE, 120),11,18) as HORA_CRUCE     " +
              ",D.PLAZA,D.PLAZA_CARRIL,d.IMPORTE,d.IMPORTE_FAC,A.SEQ  from TBL_ACL_ACLARACIONES A                  " +
              "inner join TBL_ACL_FACTURA b                                                         " +
              "on A.ID_CARGA = B.ID_CARGA                                                               " +
              "inner join TBL_ACL_TCONSOLIDA c                                                          " +
              "ON A.ID_CARGA = c.ID_CARGA                                                               " +
              "INNER JOIN TBL_ACL_GENERAL D                                                             " +
              "ON A.ID_CARGA = D.ID_CARGA where " + SQL + "";

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter daSQL = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta, conSQL);
daSQL.Fill(ds, "TBL_ACL_ACLARACIONES");
daSQL.Dispose();

OracleConnection conOracle = new OracleConnection();
conOracle.ConnectionString = "x";
conOracle.Open();

string cons_oracle = "  SELECT SEQ,TICKET,IMPORTE_D, DICTAMEN, COMENTARIO " +
                  "   FROM tbl_acl_respuestas_id             " +
                  "   WHERE ROWNUM = 1 AND TICKET IN( " + regresa__TICKS_UNION() + ")" +
                  "   ORDER BY fecha_carga DESC ";


OracleDataAdapter daOracle = new OracleDataAdapter(cons_oracle,conOracle);
daOracle.Fill(ds, "tbl_acl_respuestas_id");
daOracle.Dispose();


DataRelation StoreSaleTitleAuth = new DataRelation("SQLORACLE",
   ds.Tables["TBL_ACL_ACLARACIONES"].Columns["SEQ"],
   ds.Tables["tbl_acl_respuestas_id"].Columns["SEQ"],
   false);
ds.Relations.Add(StoreSaleTitleAuth);
```

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en el codigo he inspeccionas el "ds" podrias ver los datatable y que columnas esta generendo

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si me genera columnas

Comment: pero la idea no es validar no que genere columnas, sino que nombres les esta poniendo en cada datatable